# Не работает форма заявки

Tags: php, форма

На сайте выдаёт ошибку,(Не удалось отправить Вашу заявку. Попробуйте еще раз).
Много времени потратил разбираясь что к чему и не получается исправить.
Помогите разобраться и как исправить. [Тестовый домен ссылка](https://ale-valujskikh.pserver.ru/)

Было так.

```
define("__TO__", "info@remont-okon-berdsk.ru");
define('__SUCCESS_MESSAGE__', "Ваша заявка успешно отправлена. Мы ответим как можно скорее!");
define('__ERROR_MESSAGE__', "Не удалось отправить Вашу заявку. Попробуйте еще раз.");
define('__MESSAGE_EMPTY_FIELDS__', "Пожалуйста, заполните все поля");


//E-mail validation
function check_email($email){
    if(!@eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

//Send mail
function send_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers){
    if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, __TO__)) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => true, 'msg' => __SUCCESS_MESSAGE__));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => false, 'msg' => __ERROR_MESSAGE__));
    }
}

//Get data form and send mail
if(isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['subject'])){
    $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']);
    $subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
    $title = 'Сообщение от ';
    if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $title .= htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
    }
    else {
        $title .= $phone;
    }

    if(empty($phone) || mb_strlen($phone) < 5) {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Введите корректный телефон."));
        exit();
    } else if(empty($subject)){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Ошибка отправки заявки."));
        exit();
    } else {
        $to = __TO__;
        $message = '
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>' .$title .'</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <table style="width: 500px; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;" border="1">
            <tr style="height: 32px;">
              <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Тема сообщения:</th>
              <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $subject .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 32px;">
              <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Телефон:</th>
              <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $phone .'</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: ' .__TO__ ."\r\n";

        send_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => __MESSAGE_EMPTY_FIELDS__));
}

?>
```

А стало так правильно?

```
    <?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

define("__TO__", "info@remont-okon-berdsk.ru");
define('__SUCCESS_MESSAGE__', "Ваша заявка успешно отправлена. Мы ответим как можно скорее!");
define('__ERROR_MESSAGE__', "Не удалось отправить Вашу заявку. Попробуйте еще раз.");
define('__MESSAGE_EMPTY_FIELDS__', "Пожалуйста, заполните все поля");


//E-mail validation
function check_email($email){
    if(!@eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

//Send mail
function send_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers){
    if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, __TO__)) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => true, 'msg' => __SUCCESS_MESSAGE__));
    } else {
        print_r(error_get_last());
        echo json_encode(array('status' => false, 'msg' => __ERROR_MESSAGE__));
    }
}

//Get data form and send mail
if(isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['subject'])){
    $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']);
    $subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
    $title = 'Сообщение от ';
    if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $title .= htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
    }
    else {
        $title .= $phone;
    }

    if(empty($phone) || mb_strlen($phone) < 5) {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Введите корректный телефон."));
        exit();
    } else if(empty($subject)){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Ошибка отправки заявки."));
        exit();
    } else {
        $to = __TO__;
        $message = '
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>' .$title .'</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <table style="width: 500px; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;" border="1">
            <tr style="height: 32px;">
              <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Тема сообщения:</th>
              <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $subject .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 32px;">
              <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Телефон:</th>
              <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $phone .'</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $header = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
        $header .= "From: Новая заявка <test@gmail.com>\n\n";
        $mail = mail("test@gmail.com", "test", "test", $header); // ale-valujskikh@yandex.ru

if($mail){
   echo 'OK';
} else {
   echo 'Ошибка с mail()';
} 


   }
 } else {
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => __MESSAGE_EMPTY_FIELDS__));
}

?>
```

Comment: Может вы код покажите?

Comment: Я же ссылку на сайт вставил. view-source:https://remont-okon-berdsk.ru/ Или нужны все файлы для просмотра?

Comment: php код, а не html

Comment: Добавил php из файла contact.php

Answer (score 1):

У вас в коде идет проверка `mail()` функции, которая при отправке возвращает false.

Протестируйте её работу на элементарном примере, чтобы убедиться что ваш сервер сконфигурирован и отправляет почту через эту функцию.

```
$header = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";

$header .= "From: Новая заявка <test@gmail.com>\n\n";
$mail = mail("test@gmail.com", "test", "test", $header); // сюда надо вписать свою почту

if($mail){
   echo 'OK';
} else {
   echo 'Ошибка с mail()';
}
```

Если почта не доходит - используйте phpMailer и SMTP сервер. Бесплатные SMTP сервера для бизнеса у нас предоставляют яндекс и mail.ru

phpMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Если письмо приходит и mail() функция отрабатывает.

1. Добавьте в начало вашего файла вывод всех ошибок:

   ```
   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
   ```
2. В вашем коде после отправки и проверки статуса добавьте:

   `print_r(error_get_last())`

Должно получиться вот так:

```
//Send mail
function send_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers){
    if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, __TO__)) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => true, 'msg' => __SUCCESS_MESSAGE__));
    } else {
        print_r(error_get_last());
        echo json_encode(array('status' => false, 'msg' => __ERROR_MESSAGE__));
    }
}
```

Это выведет вам все ошибки, какие есть в коде. Дальше сможете либо разобраться с ними самостоятельно, либо дополнить вопрос и получить консультацию тут.

Comment: ,А какой емайл прописать надо тут вместо указанного, $mail = mail("test@gmail.com", и код я так понял этот в php надо прописать?

Comment: @АлександрБондарев свой. На вашу почту упадет (или нет) письмо

Comment: проверил не приходят сообщения и форма даже не показывает что отправилось сообщение.Видима на хостинге не подключена функция отправки сообщения с сайта,если я правильно считаю.

Comment: @АлександрБондарев протестируйте всё на ошибки. И я бы рекомендовал использовать phpmailer, возможно через SMTP и "почта для домена" mail.ru или яндекс. 

Нужно будет чуть повозится, но по итогу получите гарантированную, 100% рабочую почту.

Comment: Мне пришло несколько сообщений,там написано test от своего же емайла,как будто я сам себе отправил сообщение. Подскажи,как правильно сделать что бы сообщение приходило просто с пометкой новая заявка с такого та сайта и указано было имя и телефон отправителя.